# How to click on an element through Selenium ActionChain and Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am new to Python Selenium. I am stuck with this. Please help me in finding a solution.
I am trying to click this MENU1 using ActionChain.

```
locator = (By.XPATH, "//div[@title='MENU1']")
text_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(visibility_of_element_located(locator))
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(text_element).click().perform()
```

Below is the HTML:

```
<div _ngcontent-c0="" class="hyd-group-tree-node-label active" tooltipposition="bottom" title="MENU1">
    <span _ngcontent-c0="" class="ui-treenode-inner-icon fa fa-fw fa-building"></span>
    MENU1
</div>
```

Everything runs fine. No errors.
It moves to the element but I am not able to see the click movement.
I am not sure what I am missing. I tried with `text_element.click()` but it is not working. I tried in both Chrome and Firefox.

Thank you

Comment: sorry it is typo. I have edited.

Answer (score 1):

The desired element is a [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so invoke `click()` you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.hyd-group-tree-node-label.active[title='MENU1']>span.ui-treenode-inner-icon.fa.fa-fw.fa-building"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='hyd-group-tree-node-label active' and @title='MENU1']/span[@class='ui-treenode-inner-icon fa fa-fw fa-building']"))).click()
  ```

If you still want to use *ActionChains* you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.hyd-group-tree-node-label.active[title='MENU1']>span.ui-treenode-inner-icon.fa.fa-fw.fa-building")))).click().perform()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='hyd-group-tree-node-label active' and @title='MENU1']/span[@class='ui-treenode-inner-icon fa fa-fw fa-building']")))).click().perform()
  ```
- Note: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```